# How do you use zxing and its barcode scanning abilities within a UIView instead of using a ZXingWidgetController?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, zxing

I am trying to create an app in which I already have a view controller and I want the zxing capabilities (bar code scanning) to be used within this view controller. I have a tab bar controller with different view controllers, and one of them (the view controller mentioned before) should act as a scanner. How can I do this without using the ZXingWidgetController?